# Accessing Button Values Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<button type="button" value="1">1</button>
<button type="button" value="2">2</button>
<button type="button" value="3">3</button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
  })
});
```

For some reason when I click any button I am not getting my desired result which is an alert box that prints the number labelled on the clicked button. I want this alert message to pop up if any button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the jQuery library. Your should code should work as it is.

Add this above your script-tag

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For other jQuery CDN's see http://code.jquery.com/

Great tutorial for learning jQuery
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()` method:

```
 $(this).val()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" value="1">1</button>
  <button type="button" value="2">2</button>
  <button type="button" value="3">3</button>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('button').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  })
</script>

</html>
```